# Timestamp and date object in python

Tags: python, timestamp, ipython

I am confused about the timestamp object and how it works.

In this situation, the timestamp object is assigned to the variable 'time'

The following code returns the month:

```
time.month
```

However, in order to retrieve the date, you have to call the date method

```
time.date()
```

Can somebody explain why the timeStamp object is implemented like this. Why is the date retrieved through a method?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you referring to the pandas Timestamp object?

Comment: [arrow](http://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a better timestamp lib for python users